# Django translation strategy for big textual content

Tags: python, django

I will use Django translation functions/tags to translate words and small block of text. But I am wondering whether it is relevant to do the same thing for big textual content like "term of service" or "Privacy Policy" pages ?

I see 2 ways :

1) use {% blocktrans %} on the whole text, but it will make a lot of data into the gettext database, it may slow down the translation process of all other strings

2) use as many templates as languages, that is to have for the "Privacy Policy" page these kind of template files : privacy_en.html, privacy_fr.html, privacy_de.html...

What would be the correct way ?

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. use blocktrans to translate it, it's fine you big text too. Gettext is caching it
2. Use flatpages and put it there like /tos/en/ or /tos/de/ etc.

both are fine